# Equivalent definition of positive semidefinite

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis

I am reading a paper which repetitively uses the following statement, but I don't know why this is true:

**Statement** Let $A$ be a symmetric $n$-by-$n$ matrix, and $B$ be a $n$-by-$n$ matrix, $A\geq 0$ is equivalent to $\text{Tr}(A^TB)\geq 0$, $\forall B$.

**Update:**

I am not sure in the above statement on whether $B$ is an arbitrary matrix. Actually, in the paper, the matrix $B$ takes values:

(1) $B=QQ^T$, where $Q\in\mathbb{R}_{n\times 2}$ and $\|Q_{i:}\|_2^2=1$, for $1\leq i\leq n$.

(2) $B=(u\circ q)(u \circ q)^T$, where $u$ is an arbitrary vector, and $q\in\{-1,+1\}^n$

Comment: Sorry, your statement is incomple!

Comment: I assume you mean for the trace to be nonnegative and for B to also be psd. If so, this is just saying that the psd cone is self dual. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358916/dual-of-a-positive-semidefinite-cone

Comment: You mean trace of $A^TB$ bigger than $0$ for every $B$?

Comment: @BeniBogosel Updated, thanks!

Comment: Note that the matrices of the form (2) are precisely the matrices of the form $xx^T$, in which case $\operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)=x^TAx$. Matrices of the form (1) contain all $xx^T$ with $x$ of norm $\sqrt{2}$ by taking the columns of $Q$ to be equal. (I'm assuming you mean $1\leq i \leq 2$.) The equivalence follows.

Comment: $A$ is assumed to be symmetric, right?

Comment: @DustinG.Mixon 

(a) Sorry, I made a mistake on $Q_{:i}$, it should be $Q_{i:}$, thus the norm of each row of $Q$ is 1; 

(b) And are you proving (1) and (2) are equivalent? 

(c) Since $xx^T$ is psd, according to your first comment (psd cone is self dual), it is true that $A$ symmetric matrix, then $A\geq 0$ is equivalent $\text{Tr}(A^T(XX^T))\geq 0$. Is this true? 

(d) A is assumed to be symmetric, yes!

Comment: Taking $B$ and $-B$ in your statement clearly shows that $B$ cannot be arbitrary. I would assume $B$ is positive definite. Anyways, it seems that the "concise" statement is less clear than the definition itself.

Comment: @BeniBogosel yes I agree. $B$ is assumed to be psd.

Comment: Well, compiling the comments you have an answer. Taking $B = xx^T$ you obtain $x^TAx\geq 0$ and apply this to every eigenvector of $A$. Conversely, for any positive definite matrix $B$, write its Choleski decomposition $B=LL^T$ and use the fact that $A$ is psd for every column of $L$.

Comment: There are non-psd matrices $A$ such that $\operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)=0$ for every $B$ of the form (1). For example, take $A$ to be any nonzero diagonal matrix with zero trace.

Comment: ok, the converse does not hold true..